# Customizing "Send to Connection" menu action in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Looking for a quick way to modify or customize the "Send to" menu action on the library menu of a sharepoint list site. I know you can specify what library site it goes to in the advanced settings of the library settings or configure this in the admin center under records management but I need to modify that action to do more than just copy it over. I want to add in code that changes the destination copy's reference ID (if that's possible) to that of the original file where it was copied from.

Just to be clear, the following link contains the sharepoint online "send to" description I am referring to:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-Send-To-connections-for-records-management-d3bdb395-3824-49ed-9de4-c479a4bc71ea#__toc338840373

Answer (score 0):

We cannot customize the “Send to Connection” menu action in SharePoint admin center.

Because the “Send to Connection” menu action page “TA_OfficialFileAdmin.aspx” is stored under “_layout/15”. The page is stored in the server side. We cannot add any customization to the page.

https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/TA_OfficialFileAdmin.aspx